# Who is "unbeknown"?

Tags: discussion, users

While searching for an answer I stumbled upon an answer by "unbeknown". Usually if the user is deleted, we get a `user<user_id>` greyed out. But who is "unbeknown"?

Question: [How to remove an element from a list by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The post is from May 2009.

From this [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290627):

> The second case has a user name but no clickable link and no reputation or badges:
>
> ...
>
> This happens in one of two cases:
>
> ...
>
> - On accounts deleted prior to about 2011, the username would not be changed to their user code before deletion. The deletion procedure was changed at about that time, but previous deletions weren't affected.

They probably deleted their account back then and maybe anonymized their account this way.

Comment: Aah. I searched around assuming this is some sort of a common practice. Never occurred to me that it could be a username.